# Display Chrome Extension Notifications from Socket.io Server Without Opening the Extension Popup

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, websocket, notifications, popup

I have a Chrome extension built using React.js, and it communicates with a Socket.io server to receive notifications. I want to display these notifications to the user even when the extension pop-up is closed. I've tried using `chrome.notifications`, but it only seems to work when the extension pop-up is open. Is there a way to implement Chrome extension notifications that work independently of whether the extension pop-up is open or not? Please note that I cannot change the existing folder structure of my extension. Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

folder structure :

-public
-- manifest.json                                                                                                                                                                         -src
--popup.js
--background.js

I'm looking for help in making Chrome extension notifications work even when the extension pop-up is closed, and I need a solution that fits within my current folder structure and technology stack.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is to have your background worker wakeup automatically at a specific interval and handle the connection to your Socket Server.

This can be done is via the built-in chrome.alarms API : https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/api/alarms

(you will need to add alarms to the permission list in the manifest.js file)

```
permissions:[
    "notifications",
    "alarms"
]
```

For example in your background.js you can add something like this :

```
chrome.alarms.create("notificationHandler", {
    // This will serve as a recurrent check for Notifications
    delayInMinutes: DELAY_FOR_FIRST_RUN, 
    periodInMinutes: PERIOD_AT_WHICH_TO_RUN
});
chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(function(alarm) {
    if (alarm.name === "notificationHandler") {
        // CHECK FOR NOTIFICATIONS HERE 
        // Trigger the logic to display the notifications if 
        // the Socket.io server responds with a notification request
    }
});
```

This will ensure that your background worker (which is independent of the pop up window) continuously checks for notifications from your Server, as it will wakeup when receiving the various alarms.